# agrupar por mes y sumar todas las filas

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta que sumes las filas de un mes y luego que agrupe por mes por ejemplo:
Tengo 6 filas con fechas diferentes 2 son de marzo y 4 de abril, que sume todas las filas de  marzo aparte de las de abril pero que me muestre como dos filas en el resultado

[image]

```
SELECT (((sum(sensores.ph) / (count(sensores.ph))::double precision) * (100)::double precision) / (9)::double precision) AS ph_p,
(((sum(sensores.oxigeno) / (count(sensores.oxigeno))::double precision) * (100)::double precision) / (5)::double precision) AS oxigeno_p,
(((sum(sensores.temperatura) / (count(sensores.temperatura))::double precision) * (100)::double precision) / (40)::double precision) AS temperatura_p,
(((sum(sensores.turbidez) / count(sensores.turbidez)) * 100) / 100) AS turbidez_p,
(((sum(sensores.electroconductividad) / count(sensores.electroconductividad)) * 100) / 9) AS electroconductividad_p,
sensores.date,
sensores.time FROM sensores WHERE (sensores.date = (CURRENT_DATE-5)) GROUP BY sensores.date, sensores.time
```

Comment: Asumiendo que es SQL Server: podrías, hacer UNION. Primero haces un select de marzo y luego de Abril, y en medio le agregas UNION. ahí te saldrian 2 filas.

Comment: La etiqueta muestra que es mysql

Comment: GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date) en caso de que sea sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente:

```
SELECT YEAR(sensores.date),MONTH(sensores.date),
  ((
    (sum(sensores.ph) / (count(sensores.ph))::double precision) 
    * (100)::double precision) / (9)::double precision) AS ph_p,
  ((
    (sum(sensores.oxigeno) / (count(sensores.oxigeno))::double precision)
    * (100)::double precision) / (5)::double precision) AS oxigeno_p,
  ((
    (sum(sensores.temperatura) / (count(sensores.temperatura))::double precision)
    * (100)::double precision) / (40)::double precision) AS temperatura_p,
  ((
    (sum(sensores.turbidez) / count(sensores.turbidez))
    * 100) / 100) AS turbidez_p,
  ((
    (sum(sensores.electroconductividad) / count(sensores.electroconductividad))
    * 100) / 9) AS electroconductividad_p
  FROM sensores GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Tienes que extraer el mes y el año del campo date, con `MONTH` y `YEAR`, y después agrupar por éstos con `GROUP BY`. Recuerda eliminar el `WHERE`, porque entiendo que querrás ver todos los resultados y no únicamente los de hace 5 días.

Recuerda que añadir parte del dataset en formato SQL nos permite comprobar la solución que te enviamos, así como que aportes la respuesta esperada por ti para esos datos.